# How to add sparklines side by side and color the area below them in gt tables?

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

For the Week 6 of `TidyTuesday` challenge, I am trying to make a table with `gt` package using `sparkline`. My goal is to show the different tech firms' stock price trends for the last month, the last six month, and the last year. To this end, what I have done so far is given below (Apologizes for the unnecessary libraries, it just makes me more confident and that's why I keep them in the code even though I am not using them mostly.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(patchwork)
library(janitor)
library(glue)
library(ggtext)
library(gghighlight)
library(lubridate)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(gtable)
library(stringr)
library(sparkline)

dat <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2023, week = 6)
big_tech_stock_prices <- dat$big_tech_stock_prices
big_tech_companies <- dat$big_tech_companies

big_tech_stock_prices <- big_tech_stock_prices %>%
  left_join(big_tech_companies, by = "stock_symbol") %>%
  mutate(company = case_when(company == "International Business Machines Corporation" ~ "IBM",
                             TRUE ~ company))

data <- big_tech_stock_prices %>%
  group_by(company) %>%
  subset(date > make_date("2021", "12", "31") & date < make_date("2023", "01", "01")) %>%
  mutate(prices_last_year = list(close)) %>%
  subset(date > make_date("2022", "07", "01") & date < make_date("2023", "01", "01")) %>%
  mutate(prices_last_six_month = list(close)) %>%
  subset(date > make_date("2022", "11", "30") & date < make_date("2023", "01", "01")) %>%
  mutate(prices_last_month = list(close)) %>%
  select(company, prices_last_year, prices_last_six_month, prices_last_month) %>%
  unique()

data %>%
  gt() %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_year)  %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_six_month) %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_month)
```

which produced this table

[image]

Now, I have some problems with that table. First I would like to keep the company names in a separate column and therefore position the 3 different sparklines side by side, meaning that I would like to have 4 different columns, one for company names and the other 3 for each sparkline. Additionally, I would like to color the area below the lines and get rid off the points on the line, while keeping the numbers on the table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the company names in a column `ungroup` your data before passing it to `gt()`. To fill the area below the curves use `type="shaded"`. To set the fill colors and to get rid of the points use the `palette` argument. Here I set the colors for the points to `"transparent"`. Additionally I have set `label=FALSE` to remove the now transparent label for the last value:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)

data %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gt() %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_year,
    type = "shaded", label = FALSE,
    palette = c("black", rep("transparent", 3), "lightblue")
  ) %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_six_month, type = "shaded", label = FALSE, 
                   palette = c("black", rep("transparent", 3), "red")) %>%
  gt_plt_sparkline(last_month, type = "shaded", label = FALSE, 
                   palette = c("black", rep("transparent", 3), "green"))
```

[image]